# How to put add condition in for loop using java / selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I wanted to click on Add button to add items  , after clicking on add button if it displayed error then it should remove that added item and again it should click on add button to add items

Here is my code:

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("addItem")).click(); // it will add item 

    WebElement errrmsg = driver.findElement(By.id("sameAMC-invalid"));


     /* if error is displayed then it should remove added item and should
      *again add another item again clicking on add item button and should again check
      *whether it is showing error message or not if not then else condition should get
      *execute*/

    if(errrmsg.isDisplayed()) 
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("remove-Itemadd")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    else
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment")).click(); 
        Thread.sleep(6000);

    }
```

I want to put loop condition when error occured , which is it should again click on add item button and also it should check whether it is showing any error if not then it should execute in else condition ..... i don't know how to do this ...need help

Comment: Are you getting NoSuchElement exception when error is not present ?

Comment: how many times you will get an error alert?
If u put it in loop it may goes to infinity loop.Is it ok then we can use recrusive method too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use while as given below. but it goes to infinite loop and if you know the maximum count. we can include the condition to check as well.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("addItem")).click(); // it will add item 

WebElement errrmsg = driver.findElement(By.id("sameAMC-invalid"));

while(errrmsg.isDisplayed()) 
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("remove-Itemadd")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("addItem")).click(); // it will add item
    errrmsg = driver.findElement(By.id("sameAMC-invalid")); 
}

driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment")).click(); 
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

Comment: it may leads to infinite loop if keep on error alerts happen.so test case may not fail and pass too.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :  Use **findElements** instead of **findElement**

```
     driver.findElement(By.id("addItem")).click();
     while(true) {
        List<WebElement> errMsg =   UI.getdriver().findElements(By.id("sameAMC-invalid"));
        if(errMsg.size()==1) {
                driver.findElement(By.id("remove-Itemadd")).click();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                driver.findElement(By.id("addItem")).click(); 
        }
        else if(errMsg.size() == 0 ) {
            driver.findElement(By.id("button-payment")).click(); 
            Thread.sleep(6000);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Note : Code provided by @Murthi would fail , if there is no error msg.

Comment: @PrachiDalvi : Can you update us with the status of this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try next:

```
private By removeButtons = By.xpath("remove-Itemadd");
private By addButtons = By.xpath("addItem");
private By errorMsg = By.xpath("sameAMC-invalid");
private By payButton = By.id("button-payment");

private boolean isErrorOccur() {
    try {
        return driver.findElement(errorMsg).isDisplayed();
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}

public void someMethod() {
    List<WebElement> addItemsButtons = driver.findElements(addButtons);
    List<WebElement> deleteItemsButtons = driver.findElements(removeButtons);

    //it will be works if this add/remove buttons are enabled for all items - list size is the same
    for (int i = 0; i < addItemsButtons.size(); i++) {
        addItemsButtons.get(i).click();
        if (isErrorOccur()){
            deleteItemsButtons.get(i).click();
            //here need some wait, possibly
        }
    }
    driver.findElement(payButton).click();
    //here need some wait, possibly 

}
```